# Will my app be again rejected if still stores a small amount of data on iCloud after I flagged everything not to be backed up?

Tags: ios, icloud

I'm having an iOS app that moves files from Resources to NSDocumentDirectory and then I download from my server more files and put them there. My app was rejected because it stored 15mb on iCloud and I put that flag (That says that I do not want those files to be backed up on iCloud) on files after writing them to phone but my problem is that it still stores me 91.3kb.

I even putted that flag on whole App DocumentDirectory. But same result.

Will my app be rejected for that stored stuff?
How can i see what data is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No , it wont be rejected for that , I had the same situation where I wanted users to have ability to backup their database , but AppStore complained about it , then I removed only database file from iCloud backup and my app was accepted by AppStore ,

this "additional" data might be NSUserDefaults or some configuration/cache file.

Comment: I can't see what NSUserDefaults should search there as well as cache, and both of them are not generated/made by user. Only thing that remains there is my sqlite but it's size is double than the cache so I can't figure out what is there. I must be sure. Can't lose another week

Comment: do you use NSUserDefaults ? if yes , then this is also backed up to iCloud , you ca try removing NSUserDefaults and see if backup size changes , also try opening directory where App is located and see what files are in Documents and cache directory

Comment: Yes, the app was not rejected, and I also tested to convince myself that NSUserDefaults is backed up to iCloud, and you are right!. Thanks